# Auto-click a radio button but first check the sentence (label)?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, greasemonkey

I need help...
I want to click a radio button automatically...but also need to check the sentence (label)...
eg...() <-radio button

```
<label>How much is 1+1?</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2"/>()2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="3"/>()3<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="4"/>()4
```

I tried use this script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name script
// @description Auto select rpt radio button
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==

if(radio=document.evaluate('//input[@type="radio" and @value="2"]',document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue)
radio.checked=true;
```

Ok, this code..click answer ()2
but what happen if i have the following:

```
<label>How much is 1+1?</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2"/>()2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="3"/>()3<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="4"/>()4

How much is 4+2?<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="8"/>()8<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2"/>()2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="6"/>()6
```

Nothing happens because there are two values ​​called "2"..so I tried to modify the code to first check the sentence and then mark the answer (but I have not mastered it very well)...

```
if(label=document.evaluate('//label[@value="How much is 1+1?"]',document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue)&&(radio=document.evaluate('//input[@type="radio" and @value="2"]',document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue)
radio.checked=true;
```

My intention was to add a second condition that check the labels with values ​​containing "How much is 1+1?"

Could anyone guide me on how to do that?

Edit:
The sample link:
[Google docs form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dG1fdUU1bTR5R1l3dmtGS095QVYxZlE6MQ)

The page code looks something like this:
Label:

```
<label class="ss-q-title" for="entry_0">How much is 1+1
<span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span></label>
```

Radios:

```
<ul class="ss-choices"><li class="ss-choice-item"><label class="ss-choice-label"><input name="entry.0.group" value="2" class="ss-q-radio" id="group_0_1" type="radio">
2</label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><label class="ss-choice-label"><input name="entry.0.group" value="3" class="ss-q-radio" id="group_0_2" type="radio">
3</label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><label class="ss-choice-label"><input name="entry.0.group" value="4" class="ss-q-radio" id="group_0_3" type="radio">
4</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You really should be using a different `name` for the second group, e.g. `group2`; that would have allowed you to cleanly separate the 2 sets of buttons by simply adding `[name=group2]` to your filter. Checking the value of the label above it seems fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must find the radio button that is the nearest, following sibling of the `<lable>` (or text node) you care about.

jQuery makes this kind of thing easier, See [the jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/), especially [the *Selectors* section](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) and [the *Traversing* section](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing).

Here's **a complete Greasemonkey script** that will select the right button, based on the new HTML in the question (linked Google doc):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @description Auto select rpt radio button
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change introduced
    in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
//-- Note that :contains() is case-sensitive
var questionLabel   = $(
    "label.ss-q-title:contains('How much is 1+1') ~ ul.ss-choices"
).first ().find ("input[type=radio][value=2]");
questionLabel.prop ('checked', true);
```

You can also [**See the code in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fS2ks/1/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.
I've tried using the script made ​​on a form in google docs.
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dG1fdUU1bTR5R1l3dmtGS095QVYxZlE6MQ)
But nothing happen...
The previous script did work...but this had the problem that I mentioned...
Now I have set the following:

`var questionLabel   = $(
    "label:contains('How much is 1+1') ~ input[type=radio][value=2]"
).first ();
questionLabel.prop ('checked', true);`

Comment: **That Google doc doesn't have anywhere near the same structure as the question code!!!** Put the **exact, real HTML** in the question, or link to the **real** target page. ... Also, you need the `@require` and `@grant` directives as specified in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Broks,
The link is this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dG1fdUU1bTR5R1l3dmtGS095QVYxZlE6MQ
I'll edit the original question so you can see more orderly.

Comment: Thank you very much Brock..I've tested the code and works fine!
But if I try that value of radio consists of two separate words, not working. eg `("input[type=radio][value=dog crazy]");`
Code works fine is I put `("input[type=radio][value=dog]");`
Thanks again for your time

Comment: You're welcome.  I see that you've got the answer to the "crazy dog" issue in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13333094/331508) -- which is good.