# Javascript Value composed of several words [value=dog crazy]

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, greasemonkey, words

thanks for the help in this forum, I was able to get my code to work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        PARINGO
// @description Auto select rpt radio button
// @namespace   PARINGO
// @include     https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dG1fdUU1bTR5R1l3dmtGS095QVYxZlE6MQ
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change introduced
    in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
//-- Note that :contains() is case-sensitive
var questionLabel   = $(
    "label.ss-q-title:contains('How much is 1+1') ~ ul.ss-choices"
).first ().find ("input[type=radio][value=2]");
questionLabel.prop ('checked', true);

var questionLabel   = $(
    "label.ss-q-title:contains('How much is 4+2') ~ ul.ss-choices"
).first ().find ("input[type=radio][value=6]");
questionLabel.prop ('checked', true);
```

What makes this script is to check the label and mark the correct answer.
But if the response is composed of two or more separate words. No works e.g:

```
var questionLabel   = $(
        "label.ss-q-title:contains('How much is 4+2') ~ ul.ss-choices"
    ).first ().find ("input[type=radio][value=dog crazy]");
questionLabel.prop ('checked', true);
```

This works for the form in google docs:
[Form Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dG1fdUU1bTR5R1l3dmtGS095QVYxZlE6MQ)

Anybody can tell me how do that the value accept separate words?

```
("input[type=radio][value=dog crazy]")
```

Comment: Put single-quotes around "dog crazy" - `[value='dog crazy']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an attribute consists of several words than you have to use quotes like this:

```
"input[type=radio][value='dog crazy']"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the value in quotes

```
"input[type=radio][value='dog crazy']"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [jQuery's](http://jquery.com/) [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method. Put the values in quotes:

```
"input[type=radio][value='dog crazy']"
```

There are examples like this in the jQuery [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/) for [Attributes](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) in selectors. For example:

- double quotes inside single quotes: `$('a[rel="nofollow self"]')`
- single quotes inside double quotes: `$("a[rel='nofollow self']")`

Specifically, the docs state:

> Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C
>   CSS selectors, in general that means anything other than a simple
>   identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks.

Comment: It's not just jQuery. It also works in plane javascript: document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio][value='dog crazy']")

Comment: Thanks @KirillIvlev. In this case he's using the find method, hence my reference to jQuery. That is good to point out though. For those wanting info on document.querySelectorAll, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll.